# Getting location ID with Register API

Tags: square-connect

1. Is there a way to retrieve the location ID while the Register API is in use?

   - Once a transaction is complete, is it possible to get the location ID of that merchant / transaction?
2. If answer to 1. is No, what is the preferred method of obtaining transaction details without knowing the respective location id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Connect APIs to get the locations. Do you mean specifically while your app is switched over to Square Register?

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#navsection-location

Comment: Currently I am using Oauth flow to allow a merchant to do all the transaction through their square account. But that merchant can have multiple location_ids, my question is how can I get the location_id of one specific transaction made through register API.
This raises another question can I get one specific location_id of the merchant when he allows oauth flow through my app?

Comment: If you are starting with the transaction information you would need to call the [retrieve transaction](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2/#endpoint-retrievetransaction) endpoint for each location and find the one it is associated with. You can't get the specific location_id of a merchant during OAuth as applications get tied to master accounts, not individual locations.